# FaceID/TouchID success case keeps prompting for further authentication

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, localauthentication

I've implemented password/TouchID/FaceID on a view controller and when I hit the success case, I'd expect the prompt to stop firing but it just fires over and over again.

In my VC:

```
var context: LAContext!

func authenticateReturningUser() {
    context = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?

    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: &error) {
        let reason = "Verify that this is your device to continue."

        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: reason) { success, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                guard success else {
                    guard let error = error else {
                        // show error
                        return
                    }

                    switch error {
                    case LAError.userCancel:
                        // do stuff
                        return
                    default: return
                    }
                }

                print("success")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The prompt should fire once and not again if the user successfully authorizes

**Edit**:

`authenticateReturningUser` is called from the AppDelegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive` function:

```
self.coverVC?.completionHandler = { self.removeBackgroundVC() }
self.coverVC?.authenticateReturningUser()
```

Comment: Hi Zack, did you able to get the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, when showing the Touch ID prompt, your app becomes inactive. So when the prompt is dismissed, your app becomes active again, triggering the App Delegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive` again.

You might consider introducing a flag that stores whether the app became inactive because of Touch ID / Face ID etc. or because of another reason and use it in `applicationDidBecomeActive` to decide if authentication should be triggered or not.

Comment: Ah, interesting! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling `authenticateReturningUser()`? You may want to create a static boolean `authenticated` that if false, allows the call to `authenticateReturningUser()`, and if true, skips the call, and set `authenticated = true` after calling the function once.

Comment: I updated my original question to address your question